# Is it possible to turn off that method with the same name as class name is constructor?

Tags: php, class, methods

Is it possible to turn off that method with the same name as class name is constructor? In PHP.

Here is an example...

```
class Foo {
    function foo() { // This would be the constructor, but I don't want to... ='(
        echo 'I was here!';
    }
}

$foo = new Foo;
```

PHP v5.3.2 on Ubuntu.

Comment: Do not define the method

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware, no. Even if you could it's not good practice.

Comment: Okey, then the only way is to avoid calling class and method same. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible.  According to the [`__construct` Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php), it will not resolve that type of constructor for namespaced classes as of 5.3.2 (your version).  So as long as your class is namespaced, it won't behave that way.

```
namespace My;
class Foo {
    function foo() {
        echo 'I was here!';
    }
}
$foo = new Foo; // won't echo
```

Comment: +1 and since this is what I was going to suggest too, I guess we are even now ;)